# How to display total correct in measure

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I'm trying to compare difference between years in sales but  I'm having the following issue:

I have this:

```
Valor Actual = -CALCULATE(SUM(Apuntes_Resultado[Total Valor]), Apuntes_Resultado[IDEscenario]=1)
```

```
Total Valor Previo = 
VAR SubgrupoFilter = ISFILTERED(TCuentas[SubGrupo])
VAR TipoCuentaFilter = ISFILTERED(TTipoCuenta[IDTipoCuenta])
VAR Variablefilter = OR(SubgrupoFilter,TipoCuentaFilter)
VAR Resultado = IF(Variablefilter, [Valor Actual], [ActualAjust])
RETURN
Resultado
```

I use the above code to have this measure

```
`
Total Valor Final = 
VAR IDVistaDetalle = SELECTEDVALUE(TTipoCuenta[Vista Detalle])
VAR IDDetalle = SELECTEDVALUE(TTipoCuenta[Detalle])
VAR IDDetalleVisible = ISFILTERED(TCuentas[SubGrupo])
VAR Resultado = SWITCH(TRUE(),IDDetalleVisible=TRUE() && IDDetalle = 0, BLANK(),
            IDVistaDetalle = 1, [Total Valor Previo],
            IDVistaDetalle = 2, [Valor Acumulado])
RETURN Resultado`
```

this works properly. But i'm trying to normalize this values with laboral day's between years.

To this I have created the following column in my date table:

```
`Laboral Day = 
VAR EsFinDeSemana = Dates[Number Day] IN {7}
VAR EsFestivo = 
   RELATED(TablaFestivos[Fecha])

RETURN

   IF (EsFestivo || EsFinDeSemana,0,1)`
```

It works fine. Shows properly laboral days and holidays

After that, I'm using the follow measure to calculate the values adjusted by year

```
`AdjustYear = var total =CALCULATE([Total Valor Final], SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR(Dates[Date]))
 var LBCY= CALCULATE(SUMX(Dates,Dates[Laboral Day]))
 var PYLB= CALCULATE(SUMX(Dates,Dates[Laboral Day]),SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR(Dates[Date]))  

 return - DIVIDE(total, PYLB)*LBCY //value from previousyear/PYlaboraldays * CYlaboraldays
`
```

This is a sample of the result:

[image]

as you can see, it is taking the same total for two columns but values are different in rows.....
Totals for 2022 and 2021 are ok, laboral days are okey but B 2021 ajus is taking the same total of A 2021

I'm using my date table to filter by months.

Any help?

Comment: I have a feeling that `LBCY = PYLB` on a year scale, so `PYLB/LBCY=1` and this gives you that  expression `DIVIDE(total, PYLB)*LBCY` is just - `total`

Comment: hi @Mik, yes number of days is the same in year scale but some months values are different. for example in may LBCY=26 and PYLB=25 and   `PYLB/LBCY=0.96`. So for this month you have two different values A2021= 148.670 and B2021 ajus=154.617. It seems to lose the difference at the end of year and take the same number but the sum of the different values are not the same....if you do the total. Any suggestion?

Comment: The idea is to collect a table with values for each month and get  totals on a month level, then use sumx to get total of totals. I will think about it, but not sure for today. If you will succeed erlier in a struggle with the issue then, please, add the solution.

Comment: do you have YYYYMM column in your dates? Then you can summarize dates and use addcolums/summarize pair for months totals and it should work on month and year level I believe

Comment: just as idea `VAR myTbl =Addcolumns(Summarize(Dates,Dates[yearmonth]),"total",[AdjustYear]) RETURN Sumx(myTbl ,[total])

Comment: This VAR is inside my measure AdjustYear? or creating a new column? Creating a new column it returns a blank...

Comment: no, it's a new measure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
myMeasure=
VAR myTbl = 
    Addcolumns(
         Summarize(
                Dates
                ,Dates[yearMonth]  
         )
         ,"total",[AdjustYear] 
    ) 
RETURN 
    SUMX(myTbl ,[total])
```

OR

```
myMeasure=
VAR myTbl = 
    Addcolumns(
         VALUES(Dates[yearMonth]) 
         ,"total",[AdjustYear] 
    ) 
RETURN 
    SUMX(myTbl ,[total])
```

OR

```
myMeasure=
VAR myTbl = 
    Addcolumns(
         VALUES(Dates[Month]) -- the same column that you use in the matrix 
         ,"total",[AdjustYear] 
    ) 
RETURN 
    SUMX(myTbl ,[total])
```